# Error propogation through standard deviation

Tags: error-propagation

I am trying to determine the best way to propogate my error with two points if I want to either average or take the standard deviation of them.

For example, lets say I have two points 10 +-0.5 mg/L and 14 +-0.6 mg/L and I want to take the average of these points, or even the standard deviation, how do I  propogate the associated error? Do I just use the formulas for addition/subtraction/multiplication/division when necessary?

(For clarification, the error that I already have is the instrumentation error and the error I am trying to get is after measuring replicates from the same sample)

Thanks!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=combine+error

Comment: The units and notation style (+- sdev) indicate that you are estimating error in a laboratory experiment. The standard workhorse by expermentalists for computing error propagation is Gauss' law of error propagation: https://penofben.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/gausserrorpropagation2.pdf